# Magento 2 : How to modify side navigation bar in my account page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I need to modify side navigation bar on my account page as below. I tried to add some lines to customer_account.xml but its not worked.

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the **customer_account.xml** file in a code editor and look for the `customer_account_navigation` block. This block is responsible for rendering the side navigation bar on your account page.

To modify the side navigation bar, you can add, remove or edit child blocks of the **customer_account_navigation** block.

For example check this code,

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Text" name="section_title" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="text" xsi:type="string">Manage my account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: i need to add section titles linke "Manage my account " top to My Account navigation link

Comment: Check above the updated code

Comment: i got this error after add above code   **Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Text
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Text does not exist**

Comment: Try this Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

Answer (score 1):

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="account_section_title">
    <arguments>
             <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"> <![CDATA[<span class="account_section_title">Manage my account</span>]]></argument>
        </arguments>        
</block>
```

This code i used as the solution.